# javascript regexp for validating url without http in the beginning

Tags: javascript

I want to validate a javascript string using regexp for URL.

I don't wan't to force http:// in the beginning.

What is the correct regexp, since I have the next one to include http:

```
var pattern = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the regex you already have, but make ftp, http and https optional. See following:

```
var pattern = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```